Branch circuit overload did not trip breaker. What's my next step?
I have a microwave and kettle plugged into different outlets on the same circuit protected by a 20 amp breaker. The wire is 12 AWG.
The microwave is rated 14A @ 120V. I confirmed with watt meter: 1670W.
The kettle is rated 1200W. I confirmed with watt meter: 1180W.
I just bought the watt meter and was testing appliances. Without thinking, while the microwave was running I thought I'd use the time to test the kettle watts. I had already tested the microwave. When the kettle showed 1180W I had a light bulb moment! Why didn't the breaker trip?
Today I inspected the outlet connections and they seem tight and fine. I have a GE 30 slot panel that is full. It allows 1/2" breakers in the last 5 slots for a total of 40 breakers. I can't find a GE thin AFCI breaker which I thought about to maybe find a hidden arc.
Should I try another breaker as a test? Seems unlikely a breaker would fail "ON".

Quite a few kitchen(and some others) circuits use MWBC that use two hot wires and a single shared neutral, so each half the circuit/receptacle can have the full twenty amps.  Check the breakers for that circuit, they probably are a double breaker or two singles with a handle tie.

I did check and the circuit is isolated to itself. However, I had never heard of MWBC and learned something. I have a different circuit pair that may have a shared neutral. I need to take the panel off again to verify. At least now I understand the implications. Thanks!

It's unlikely that a GE breaker would fail "on" - certain others do have that failure mode, and the correct action is "don't buy  house with them" or "replace the panel ASAP before it burns your house down." If discovered when buying the house, get a reduction in price to cover the work. GE does not happen to be one of those. Federal Pacific StabLok and Zinsco are two brands off the top of my head. But in this case it's merely the time .vs. overload as already answered.

For how long did you have 2850W, or 24A?
MCCB's have a trip curve:

Picture from above link - ABB What you need to know about MCB trip curves.
24A is a small overload, under 1.2 times nominal current. This is a level of overload that a MCB can hold for minutes. Thus it's not very surprising that it didn't trip during your test. Keep that level of power for ten minutes and it should trip.
Instant trip likely requires 5-10 times the nominal current, e.g. 100-200A for a 20A device.
To verify that the breaker works, you would have to perform two different tests, as they have two different trip mechanisms:

Thermal (slow)
Electromagnetic (fast)

To test thermal, I would use a load roughly twice rated capacity. This should trip breaker in under 20 seconds. In addition, you need a dead short circuit, which will give electromagnetic trip. To verify electromagnetic trip you probably need a fairly advanced current measurement device to measure inrush current.
The electromagnetic trip is also why we have to calculate wire gauge to allow a sufficient short circuit current to trigger the electromagnetic trip.

What a great answer! I knew breakers could handle a "little" over amperage for a "little" while but never thought it would be minutes. Great source. Thanks!
